# How to pass multiple argument to a callback function? (ROS, c++)

Tags: c++, callback, arguments, ros

In order to change the robot's behavior according to the request sent by the client, a callback function was created. However, the class variable cannot be transferred to the callback function because moveit setting class became local class variable. I tried to pass local class variable to callback function as arguments to I saw a post telling me to use boost::bind, and I tried it, but an "error: use of deleted function boost~" occurred. Is there any solution?

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "leap_panda/machine_to_robot.h"
#include "boost/bind.hpp"
    
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h>
#include <moveit/planning_scene_interface/planning_scene_interface.h>
    
#include <moveit_msgs/DisplayRobotState.h>
#include <moveit_msgs/DisplayTrajectory.h>
    
#include <moveit_msgs/AttachedCollisionObject.h>
#include <moveit_msgs/CollisionObject.h>
    
#include <moveit_visual_tools/moveit_visual_tools.h>

    
bool success = 0;
namespace rvt = rviz_visual_tools;
using namespace rvt;
 
bool operation(leap_panda::machine_to_robot::Request &req, leap_panda::machine_to_robot::Response &res, moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface &move_group, moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualTools &visual_tools, Eigen::Isometry3d &text_pose, robot_state::JointModelGroup* joint_model_group)
{
  if(req.gesture_type == 1)
  {
    geometry_msgs::Pose target_pose1;
    target_pose1.orientation.w = 1.0;
    target_pose1.position.x = 0.5;
    target_pose1.position.y = 0.5;
    target_pose1.position.z = 0.5;

    move_group.setPlanningTime(10.0);
    move_group.setPoseTarget(target_pose1);

    moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan my_plan;

    success = (move_group.plan(my_plan) == moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode::SUCCESS);

    ROS_INFO_NAMED("tutorial", "Visualizing plan 1 (pose goal) %s", success ? "" : "FAILED");

    ROS_INFO_NAMED("tutorial", "Visualizing plan 1 as trajectory line");
    visual_tools.publishAxisLabeled(target_pose1, "pose1");
    visual_tools.publishText(text_pose, "Pose Goal", rvt::WHITE, rvt::XLARGE);
    visual_tools.publishTrajectoryLine(my_plan.trajectory_, joint_model_group);
    visual_tools.trigger();
    visual_tools.prompt("Press 'next' in the RvizVisualToolsGui window to continue the demo");

    move_group.move(); 

    res.robot_state = 0;
    res.success = 1;

  }
  else if(req.gesture_type == 4)
  {
    geometry_msgs::Pose target_pose1;
      target_pose1.orientation.w = 0.0;
      target_pose1.position.x = 0.5;
      target_pose1.position.y = -0.2;
    target_pose1.position.z = 0.5;

    move_group.setPlanningTime(10.0);
    move_group.setPoseTarget(target_pose1);

    moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan my_plan;

    success = (move_group.plan(my_plan) == moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode::SUCCESS);


    ROS_INFO_NAMED("tutorial", "Visualizing plan 2 (pose goal) %s", success ? "" : "FAILED");

    ROS_INFO_NAMED("tutorial", "Visualizing plan 2 as trajectory line");
    visual_tools.publishAxisLabeled(target_pose1, "pose2");
    visual_tools.publishText(text_pose, "Pose Goal", rvt::WHITE, rvt::XLARGE);
    visual_tools.publishTrajectoryLine(my_plan.trajectory_, joint_model_group);
    visual_tools.trigger();
    visual_tools.prompt("Press 'next' in the RvizVisualToolsGui window to continue the demo");

    move_group.move(); 
     

    res.robot_state = 0;
    res.success = 1;
  }


  return true;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "robot");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

    static const std::string PLANNING_GROUP = "panda_arm";

    moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface move_group(PLANNING_GROUP);

    moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface planning_scene_interface;

    const robot_state::JointModelGroup* joint_model_group =
    move_group.getCurrentState()->getJointModelGroup(PLANNING_GROUP);

    
    moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualTools visual_tools("panda_link0");
    visual_tools.deleteAllMarkers();

    visual_tools.loadRemoteControl();

    Eigen::Isometry3d text_pose = Eigen::Isometry3d::Identity();
    text_pose.translation().z() = 1.75;
    visual_tools.publishText(text_pose, "MoveGroupInterface Demo", rvt::WHITE, rvt::XLARGE);

  visual_tools.trigger();

  ROS_INFO_NAMED("tutorial", "Planning frame: %s", move_group.getPlanningFrame().c_str());

    ROS_INFO_NAMED("tutorial", "End effector link: %s", move_group.getEndEffectorLink().c_str());

  ROS_INFO_NAMED("tutorial", "Available Planning Groups:");
    std::copy(move_group.getJointModelGroupNames().begin(), move_group.getJointModelGroupNames().end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ", "));
    visual_tools.prompt("Press 'next' in the RvizVisualToolsGui window to start the demo");

   ros::ServiceServer robot_server = nh.advertiseService("machine_to_robot",1, boost::bind(&operation, _1, move_group,visual_tools,text_pose,joint_model_group));

  while(ros::ok()){
  
  ros::spinOnce();
  }
  //ros::shutdown();
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text.  All error messages should be included as text verbatim in the question.

Comment: Looks like `MoveGroupInterface` is non-copyable. I don't have ROS with me to try and compile it, but I think simple lambda should work `[&move_group (... and others)](const auto& arg) { return operation(arg, move_group, (... etc ...)); }` ; more or less;

Comment: Alternatively: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.purpose.using_bind_with_functions_and_fu use `boost::cref` around your bind args - this way you should avoid the copy.

Comment: The code provided seems to contain pretty much irrelevant stuff – is it really minimal (see [mre])? You increase chances to get answers by reducing the amount of code people have to read – we are pretty lazy here on SO...

Comment: I'm sorry. I couldn't follow the rules because it's been a while since I asked question. And thank you for answer. I'll give it a try it.